# Why would the order of linking libs cause runtime errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I have an unmanaged C++ project, which produces runtime errors when the linker libraries (Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies) are listed in a specific order but runs fine when I change the order of libraries. I understand why the order could cause Link errors ([Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)) but how could it possibly cause runtime errors? I observed this in VS2005, 2008 and 2010.

Comment: Are you mixing compiler versions or debug and release?

Comment: No, all libs are built by the same compiler in the same flavour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of runtime errors? You don't say, so we have to guess.

Here's one way a runtime error could happen: If two unrelated libraries expose different functions that happen to have the same name, the linker will pick the first implementation it finds.

If you intended to call `draw()` from `paint.lib`, but `gunfight.lib` is earlier in the linker list, you will be calling the wrong `draw()` with unpredictable consequences.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, I thought the linker would complain in this case. I didn't specify the runtime errors, because I didn't know how to present them here without giving a lot of context. I'll investigate whether what you suggest is the cause.

Comment: Yes, the barebones error would probably not help; it would have to be distiller into something like "the wrong function is called". Here's an idea: usually linkers have 'verbose' parameters that will spew in painful detail what they are doing. Find out what that parameter is for your particular toolset and use it with both link orders. Run the output through a diff tool and see if anything stands out. Please let us know how it turns out one way or another. Good luck.